# How to add a flag constraint in Pyomo?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, battery

I am trying to simulate a battery dispatch models with charging and discharging constraints. The BESS is charging from a Solar PV system. When I run the model currently, there are some time periods when the BESS is charging and discharging at the same time. How can I add a flag such that when Charge >, Discharge =0 and vice-versa.

```
 def market_constraintx0(model, t):

        return (model.Charge[t] <= df.loc[t,'PVGeneration']*stripeff)

    model.market_rulex0 = Constraint(model.T, rule=market_constraintx0)

    def market_constraintx1(model, t):

        return (model.Charge[t] + model.RegDown[t]  <= model.ChargeMax)

    model.market_rulex1 = Constraint(model.T, rule=market_constraintx1)

    def market_constraintx2(model, t):

        return ( model.Discharge[t] + model.RegUp[t]  <= model.DischargeMax)

    model.market_rulex2 = Constraint(model.T, rule=market_constraintx2)


    def charge_soc(model, t):

        return model.RegUp[t] + model.Discharge[t]  <= model.SoC[t] * stripeff     ###Battery discharge and regup capacity is limited by SOC

    model.charge_soc = Constraint(model.T, rule=charge_soc)

    def discharge_soc(model, t):

        return model.RegDown[t] + model.Charge[t] <= (model.SoCmax - model.SoC[t])/stripeff        ### Battery can be charged by the amount of capacity left to charge.

    model.discharge_soc = Constraint(model.T, rule=discharge_soc)
```

Answer (score 0):

The constraint

```
x >= 0 or y >= 0
```

is sometimes called a complementarity condition. It can also be written as:

```
x * y = 0
```

(I assume x and y are non-negative variables). There are different ways to solve this:

- complementarity solver. Some solvers support this kind of constraints directly. Complementarity constraints inside a math programming model is known as MPEC (Mathematical Programming with Equilibrium Constraints). So these solvers are sometimes called MPEC solvers.
- nonlinear formulation. The constraint x*y=0 is not very easy, but a global solver should be able to handle this reliably. However these solvers only handle relatively small models (compared to local solvers).
- discrete formulation. Formulate the OR condition using binary variables or a SOS1 construct. This is especially useful if the rest of the model is linear.

You may want to look into **pyomo.mpec**.  For further information see [link](https://prod-ng.sandia.gov/techlib-noauth/access-control.cgi/2015/155584.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to (mixed-integer) linear formulations, you can also look for indicator constraints, which are discussed generally [in this question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/231/when-to-use-indicator-constraints-versus-big-m-approaches-in-solving-mixed-int). Some solvers like CPLEX and Gurobi seem to have specific constraint types for indicator constraints, but I'm not familiar with how to use those within Pyomo.

In general, you can get similar functionality by using a **"Big M" formulation**. In your case, something like:

```
model.Indicator = Var(model.T, within=Binary)
model.M = Param(initialize=1000)

def charge_indicator_constraint(model, t):
    return model.M * model.Indicator[t] >= model.Charge[t]
...

def discharge_indicator_constraint(model, t):
    return (1 - model.M) * model.Indicator >= model.Discharge[t]
...
```

As the discussed in the question I linked to, picking the right value of `model.M` is important to keep your model formulation "tight", and in your case, you would probably tie it directly to the power rating of your BESS.